# "color" vs "colour" when calling ggfortify + autoplot on a PCA object

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

This is the first time I've encountered an issue with not using the Queen's spelling: if I call `autoplot` with `colour=` I get the points colored according to the referenced variable, but if I write `color=` the argument gets ignored and everything is plotted in black. Code:

```
library(ggfortify)
library(cowplot)

pca_res <- prcomp(iris[1:4], scale = TRUE)

british <- autoplot(pca_res, data=iris, colour='Species')
us <- autoplot(pca_res, data=iris, color='Species')

plot_grid(british, us, labels=c('colour', 'color'))
```

[image]

Is this an issue with `ggplot2` itself (I doubt it, I've never run into it previously), with `autoplot` or with `ggfortify`? I'd like to report it as a bug but I'm not 100% sure where the problem is. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like `autoplot` calls `autoplot.prcomp` which is an alias for [`autoplot.pca_common`](https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/blob/912ba6d39feb1537b30997632b1d125500c1058d/R/fortify_stats.R#L252-L342) that calls [`ggbiplot`](https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/blob/9eaefc64ace42659bea852e28bd583e93f5a3aad/R/plotlib.R#L510-L546) that has no *color* argument, I'd say `maintainer("ggfortify")` to commend them that "u" matters.

Comment: For future visitors, related issue (not fixed yet): https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/issues/224

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue has now been fixed.](https://github.com/sinhrks/ggfortify/pull/225)